# How to check if value NOT EXISTS or NULL in object using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object in javascript

```
var obj = {
   "a": null,
   "b": "test2"
}
```

How do I check that test1 NULL or NOT EXISTS in the object as a value?
and how to change that "a" object values (null) to "this object is null" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check if exists:**

```js
var obj = {
  "a": null,
  "b": "test2"
}

console.log(
  Object.keys(obj).indexOf("a") != -1
)
```

**Check for null**

Note I am testing SPECIFICALLY for null. If you need to test for empty or undefined, then the code will be different

for..in

```js
var obj = {
  "a": null,
  "b": "test2"
}
for (let k in obj) obj[k] = obj[k] !== null ? obj[k] : "This was null"
console.log(obj)
```

Object.keys and forEach:

```js
var obj = {
  "a": null,
  "b": "test2"
}
Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => obj[k] = obj[k] !== null ? obj[k] : "This was null")
console.log(obj)
```

Object.entries and forEach

```js
var obj = {
  "a": null,
  "b": "test2"
}

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (value === null) obj[key] = "This was null"
})
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
obj.a !== null || obj.a !== undefined
```

Comment: It would be good if you can provide an explanation for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
  "a": null,
  "b": "test2",
  "c":"",
  "d":0,
}
console.log()
if (obj.a) {
  console.log('a value exists!');
} else {
  console.log('a value not exists!');
}
if (obj.c) {
  console.log('c value exists!');
} else {
  console.log('c value not exists!');
}
if (typeof(obj.d)=== "number" && obj.d === 0) {
  console.log('d value exists!');
} else {
  console.log('d value not exists!');
}
```

Simple You can check using the object's element.

Comment: If you have `var obj = {"a": "", "b": "test2"}`, this will fail, same with other falsey values

Comment: @NickParsons Thank you for reminding me, Please check the updated answer... :-)

Comment: Your updated answer will still treat "", 0 and other falsy values the same

Comment: @mplungjan Sir I did not get it.

Comment: "c":"", and "c":0, will both log "c value does not exist" because 0 and empty are both `falsy` - ditto "c":false

Comment: @mplungjan Okay I got it :-)

Comment: @mplungjan answer updated thanks for correcting me :-)

Comment: But the console.log is wrong. d DOES exist and is 0

Comment: @mplungjan sorry I forgot the condition

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check that object in javascript has a property or not. You can used !! opertaor for that fro e.g:

```
var obj = {
  "a": null,
  "b": "test2"
}

console.log(!!obj.b)  // true
console.log(!!obj.c)  // false
```